# How can I store user input properly in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to make a program that functions like a calendar, so that the user can add an event to a certain weekday, then the program has to store that event for the next time the user opens the program, but it's not working and the code looks messy.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I fix it?
Here is the code:

````
import pickle
import os

from datetime import date

#Menu
print("Welcome to time management")
print("What do you want to do?")
print("1.What to do today")
print("2.Add event")

#Events
choice = input()

#Event List
if choice == 1:
    if date.today().weekday() == 0:
        pickle.load(event_monday_1)
        print("Today you have to: ", event_monday_1)
    if date.today().weekday() == 1:
        print("today you have to: ", event_tuesday_1)
    if date.today().weekday() == 2:
        print("today you have to: ", event_wednesday_1)
    if date.today().weekday() == 3:
        print("today you have to: ", event_thursday_1)
    if date.today().weekday() == 4:
        print("today you have to: ", event_friday_1)
    if date.today().weekday() == 5:
        print("today you have to: ", event_saturday_1)
    if date.today().weekday() == 6:
        print("today you have to: ", event_sunday_1)
#Add event
if choice == 2:
    print("How many events? (1 events per day)")
    eventN = input()
    if eventN == 1:
        print("1 event \n What event is it?")
        event1 = input()
        print("What day do you want to store the event?")
        event1D = input()
        if event1D == 0:
            event_monday_1 = [event1]
            pickle.dump(event_monday_1)
        if event1D == 1:
            event_tuesday_1 = [event1]
            pickle.dump(event_tuesday_1)
        if event1D == 2:
            event_wednesday_1 = [event1]
            pickle.dump(event_wednesday_1)
        if event1D == 3:
            event_thursday_1 = [event1]
            pickle.dump(event_thursday_1)
        if event1D == 4:
            event_friday_1 = [event1]
            pickle.dump(event_friday_1)
        if event1D == 5:
            event_saturday_1 = [event1]
            pickle.dump(event_saturday_1)
        if event1D == 6:
            event_sunday_1 = [event1]
            pickle.dump(event_sun_1)```
````

Comment: You might need `choice = int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

In python2 and python3, taking user inputs is a bit different.

```
### Python 2.7.16 (default, Feb 29 2020, 01:55:37)
>>> t = input()
12
>>> t
12
>>> type(t)
<type 'int'>
>>> exit()

### Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
>>> t = input()
12
>>> t
'12'
>>> type(t)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

As @Chis mentioned, you should use `int` to typecase user input is the way to go.

Also try to create some methods to make code readable.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, your first issue is that input() will always return a string. If the string is numeric characters, you need to change it to an integer if you want to treat it that way.

```
"0" != 0
```

As for the messiness, and then also in your data-retrieval section, you wouldn't want to keep loading and writing a single variable to or from the file. Instead, I would recommend storing all of the calendar data in a single data type - a dictionary.

instead of:

```
event_monday1 = "This is my event"
event_tuesday1 = "This is another event"
```

You'll want:

```
events = {
  "monday": "this is my event",
  "tuesday": "this is another event"
}
```

By doing it this way, you don't need to keep writing to file and loading from file. You can load the file once at the beginning, and write it back once at the end. Accessing your data would instead look like this:

instead of....

```
event_monday1
```

you would use....

```
events["monday"]
```

Here is a complete working picture, fixing several things in your code, but with comments you'll hopefully find useful:

```
import json
import os

from datetime import date

#Menu
print("Welcome to time management")
print("What do you want to do?")
print("1.What to do today")
print("2.Add event")

#Events
choice = input()
#convert to integer
choice = int(choice)

#Load Data
data_path = "eventdata.json"
#Check if the file already exists (it won't exist the first time you use it)
if os.path.exists(data_path):
    with open(data_path, 'r') as f:
        events = json.load(f)
else:
    #If it doesn't exist, create a fresh empty dictionary
    events = {}


#Event List
if choice == 1:
    #We'll define a default case, to be overwritten if an event is found today.
    event = "Nothing scheduled"
    if date.today().weekday() == 0:
        #First, you need to check that such a variable exists in your schedule
        if "monday" in events.keys():
            #If so, that's what you want to grab
            event = events["monday"]
    if date.today().weekday() == 1:
        if "tuesday" in events.keys():
            event = events["tuesday"]
    if date.today().weekday() == 2:
        if "wednesday" in events.keys():
            event = events["wednesday"]
    if date.today().weekday() == 3:
        if "thursday" in events.keys():
            event = events["thursday"]
    if date.today().weekday() == 4:
        if "friday" in events.keys():
            event = events["friday"]
    if date.today().weekday() == 5:
        if "saturday" in events.keys():
            event = events["saturday"]
    if date.today().weekday() == 6:
        if "sunday" in events.keys():
            event = events["sunday"]
    print("Today you have to: ", event)


#Add event
if choice == 2:
    print("How many events? (1 events per day)")
    eventN = input()
    eventN = int(eventN)
    #instead of writing a separate case for each possible answer, we'll loop.
    for i in range(eventN):
        print(f"Event {i + 1}: \n What event is it?")
        event = input()
        print("What day do you want to store the event?")
        event_day = input()
        event_day = int(event_day)
        if event_day == 0:
            events["monday"] = event
        if event_day == 1:
            events["tuesday"] = event
        if event_day == 2:
            events["wednesday"] = event
        if event_day == 3:
            events["thursday"] = event
        if event_day == 4:
            events["friday"] = event
        if event_day == 5:
            events["saturday"] = event
        if event_day == 6:
            events["sunday"] = event
    #Store updated events to file
    with open(data_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(events, f)
```